# How to calculate the determinant of a matrix with all the elements are strings?

Tags: c#

**The goal** ：

To calculate the determinant of a matrix like this:[image: Matrix]

**What I have done**：

1. I create a matrix with all the elements are in strings.
2. I'm using the normal recursion to calculate the determinant. And I also use operator Overloading on + , * and - .

This is the code for determinant calculation

```
    public BoolDK Determinant(BoolDK[,] Inputmatrix)
    {
        if (Inputmatrix.GetLength(1) == 1)
        {
            DeResult = Inputmatrix[0, 0];
            return DeResult;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Inputmatrix.GetLength(1) == 2)
            {

                DeResult = (Inputmatrix[0, 0] * Inputmatrix[1, 1]) - (Inputmatrix[0, 1] * Inputmatrix[1, 0]);
                return DeResult;


            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Inputmatrix.GetLength(1); i++)
                {
                    BoolDK[,] InsideMatrix = new BoolDK[Inputmatrix.GetLength(1), Inputmatrix.GetLength(1)];
                    InsideMatrix = EliminateColumn(Inputmatrix, i);
                    BoolDK[,] InsideMatrix_2 = new BoolDK[Inputmatrix.GetLength(1), Inputmatrix.GetLength(1)];
                    InsideMatrix_2 = EliminateRow(InsideMatrix, 0);
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        DeResult = Inputmatrix[0, i] * Determinant(InsideMatrix_2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Inputmatrix[0, i].MatrixElement != "0")
                        {
                            DeResult = DeResult + (Inputmatrix[0, i] * Determinant(InsideMatrix_2));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DeResult = DeResult;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return DeResult;
        }
```

And this is the code for Operator Overloading

```
        public static BoolDK operator *(BoolDK op1, BoolDK op2)
    {
        BoolDK Result = new BoolDK();

        if (op1.MatrixElement == "0" | op2.MatrixElement == "0")
        {
            Result.MatrixElement = "0";
        }
        else if (op1.MatrixElement == op2.MatrixElement)
        {
            Result.MatrixElement = "1";
        }
        else if (op1.MatrixElement == "1" & op1.MatrixElement != "1")
        {
            Result.MatrixElement = op2.MatrixElement;
        }
        else if (op1.MatrixElement != "1" & op1.MatrixElement != "\u00AC" & op2.MatrixElement == "1")
        {
            Result.MatrixElement = op1.MatrixElement;
        }
        else if ((op1.MatrixElement.Length + op2.MatrixElement.Length) == 2)
        {
            Result.MatrixElement = op1.MatrixElement + "*" + op2.MatrixElement;
        }
        else if (op2.MatrixElement.Contains("\u2299"))
        {
            Result.MatrixElement = op1.MatrixElement + "*" + op2.MatrixElement;
        }
        else if (op2.MatrixElement.Contains("\u2295"))
        {
            Result.MatrixElement = op1.MatrixElement + "*" + op2.MatrixElement;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!op2.MatrixElement.Contains("||"))
            {
                Result.MatrixElement = "(" + op1.MatrixElement + ")*(" + op2.MatrixElement + ")";

            }
            else
            {
                string[] temporarystring = op2.MatrixElement.Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                int Lengthoftemporarystring = temporarystring.Length;
                string[] temporarystring2 = new string[Lengthoftemporarystring];
                for (int i = 0; i < Lengthoftemporarystring; i++)
                {
                    temporarystring2[i] = op1.MatrixElement + "*" + temporarystring[i];
                }
                String Stringresult;
                String Sep = "||";
                Stringresult = String.Join(Sep, temporarystring2);
                Result.MatrixElement = Stringresult;
            }
        }

        return Result;
    }//Operator Overloading


    public static BoolDK operator -(BoolDK op1, BoolDK op2)
    {
        BoolDK Result = new BoolDK();
        if (op1.MatrixElement != "0" & op2.MatrixElement != "0")
        {
            Result.MatrixElement = "(" + op1.MatrixElement + ")||(" + op2.MatrixElement + ")";
        }
        else if (op1.MatrixElement != "0" & op2.MatrixElement == "0")
        {
            Result = op1;
        }
        else if (op1.MatrixElement == "0" & op2.MatrixElement != "0")
        {
            Result.MatrixElement = "(" + op1.MatrixElement + ")||(" + op2.MatrixElement + ")";
        }
        else if (op1.MatrixElement == "0" & op2.MatrixElement == "0")
        {
            Result.MatrixElement = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            Result.MatrixElement = "(" + op1.MatrixElement + ")||(" + op2.MatrixElement + ")";
        }

        return Result;
    }//Operator Overloading(checked!!!!)


    public static BoolDK operator +(BoolDK op1, BoolDK op2)
    {
        BoolDK Result = new BoolDK();
        if (op1.MatrixElement != "0" & op2.MatrixElement != "0")
        {
            Result.MatrixElement = op1.MatrixElement + "||" + op2.MatrixElement;
        }
        else if (op1.MatrixElement != "0" & op2.MatrixElement == "0")
        {
            Result = op1;
        }
        else if (op1.MatrixElement == "0" & op2.MatrixElement != "0")
        {
            Result = op2;
        }
        else if (op1.MatrixElement == "0" & op2.MatrixElement == "0")
        {
            Result.MatrixElement = "0";
        }

        return Result;

    }//Operator Overloading
```

**The Problem is**:

This method can not calculate a matrix with the dimension over 12*12, which causes OutOfMemoryException. And the goal is to calculate 25*25 matrix.

Is recursion slow down the performance or strings operations slow down the performance?

So, anyone has a idea how to make this work? Thank you !!! Danke!!!

Comment: If by "normal recursion" you mean computing the determinant of an `n*n` matrix by computing the determinants of all the `(n-1)*(n-1)` submatrices and summing them, that will never work for something of size 25. Work out the number of multiplications you have to do; it's enormous. Instead, use the LU decomposition technique.

Comment: @EricLippert yes, I have thought about that this afternoon. But i'm not sure if the LU decomposition can handle the matrix with all the elements are in strings.

Comment: I would not use strings to represent Boolean operations. Were I attempting to solve this problem I would make classes that represent Boolean operations and put the smarts into that thing. You might be able to solve this without running out of memory by memoizing the operations.

Comment: I've been meaning to write a series of blog articles on how to write code that optimizes Boolean operations, but it will have to wait until I am done my long series on probabilistic programming.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure your operator overloads are as efficient as they could be.  For example you have `1+1` producing `1||1`, when it could just produce `1`.

Comment: The problem with the LU technique is that you cannot do multiplicative inverses in your algebraic system, is that right?

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, it's very inefficient using strings to represent Boolean operations. And someday I hope I can read your blog!!! And thanks for your advice, I will try to optimize. Right, using Laplace expansion seems like the only option here.